# WPF: Speech Grammar with multiple active rules not working

Tags: c#, wpf, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have created a `Grammar` using XML for use with the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` type.

The grammar file works when I have only ONE rule referenced in the 'root' rule, but does NOT work when I have more than one rule referenced in the 'root' rule.

As far as I can see I have followed the instructions detailed in the docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh361609%28v%3Doffice.14%29)

Here is the Grammer XML file:

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US" root="topLevel"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

  <rule id="topLevel">
    <ruleref uri="#commandOne"/>
    <ruleref uri="#commandTwo"/>
  </rule>

  <rule id="commandOne">
    <one-of>
      <item> run tests </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

  <rule id="commandTwo">
    <one-of>
      <item> open </item>
      <item> goto </item>
    </one-of>
    <ruleref uri="#toolRule"/>
  </rule>

  <rule id="toolRule">
    <one-of>
      <item> spanner </item>
      <item> wrench </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

</grammar>
```

Here is the code I am using to set up and load the grammar file:

```
          speechRecogniser.SpeechRecognized += SpeechRecogniser_SpeechRecognized;
          speechRecogniser.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(@"Speech\TestGrammar.xml"));
          speechRecogniser.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
          speechRecogniser.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Please can anyone tell me why no rules work from the XML when I have >1 rules referenced in rule 'topLevel'?

Comment: could you show your code  you are using the command recognized?

Comment: @Frenchy, if you mean the SpeechRecognized event handler then at the moment it is just empty, but with a breakpoint on it that is not being hit.

Comment: following your sample you are waiting voice command like: "run tests open spanner" or "run tests open wrench"  (4 words) you confirm that?

Comment: @Frenchy, I am waiting for the phrases like 'run tests'  or 'open spanner' to be recognised. Not to have them all merged like you have indicated.

Comment: No comment about my answer?

Comment: @Frenchy, apologies for the late reply. Yes, your answer looks interesting. I did not think about doing that. In the meantime I have decided to abandon using Speech Recognition as no equivalent API exists in .NET Core, which I plan to migrate to. Thanks for your suggestion however.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this syntax:

```
<rule id="toplevel" scope="public">
  <one-of>
    <item> <ruleref uri="#commandOne"/> </item>
    <item> <ruleref uri="#commandTwo"/> </item>
  </one-of>
</rule>
```